# GSUtil does not have access to object created in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

My App Engine application created an object. I am now attempting to use gsutil to change the acls but cannot do so even though I am an owner of the project:

```
$ gsutil getacl gs://mybucket/3c3765c2e7d4bfe6320c54fa4c8538dc.png
GSResponseError: status=403, code=AccessDenied, reason=Forbidden.

$ gsutil ls -L gs://mybucket/3c3765c2e7d4bfe6320c54fa4c8538dc.png
gs://mybucket/3c3765c2e7d4bfe6320c54fa4c8538dc.png:
    Creation time:  Mon, 31 Dec 2012 00:17:06 GMT
    Cache-Control:  public, max-age=3600, no-transform
    Content-Length: 30317
    Content-Type:   image/png
    ETag:           3df68afeffcba39dbfdf568d78bb4c72
    ACL:            ACCESS DENIED. Note: you need FULL_CONTROL permission
                    on the object to read its ACL.
TOTAL: 1 objects, 30317 bytes (29.61 KB)
```

Why don't I have FULL_CONTROL to this object?

From https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gs-discussion/-aQISyaeeFo/9L_ML2SnV0MJ

Comment: Have you tried to find it in the web UI (storage.cloud.google.com) ?

Comment: The object is there but I can't read it. To repro try this: gsutil setdefacl private gs://mybucket and then create an object in mybucket with app engine and attempt to read it. Or do gsutil setdefacl public-read gs://mybucket and attempt to use gsutil to change the acls of an object created in app engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine usually uses the app's service account to access Google Cloud Storage. The service account is a different user from the gmail account you use with gsutil.

Having `WRITE` or `FULL_CONTROL` access to a bucket means you can delete objects. It does not mean you can read objects or change the object ACLs. For this you need `READ` or `FULL_CONTROL` access on the object. Object ACLs are orthogonal to bucket ACLs.

So what is happening is:

- The bucket acl allows both you and the service account to write to the bucket.
- The service account creates a new object, applying the bucket's default object acl.
- The bucket's [default object acl](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#defaultobjects) does not grant you full control to this object.

Run `gsutil getdefacl gs://mybucket` and make sure the default object acl grants you or one of your groups `FULL_CONTROL` to new objects.

If it does not then edit the xml document to contain something like the following and run `gsutil setdefacl acl.xml gs://mybucket`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AccessControlList>
 <Entries>
  <Entry>
   <Scope type="UserByEmail">
    <EmailAddress>example@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
   </Scope>
   <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
   <Scope type="GroupByEmail">
    <EmailAddress>foo@googlegroups.com</EmailAddress>
   </Scope>
   <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
   <Scope type="GroupByEmail">
    <EmailAddress>group@mydomain.com</EmailAddress>
   </Scope>
   <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
  </Entry>
 </Entries>
</AccessControlList>
```

Comment: "Having WRITE or FULL_CONTROL access to a bucket means you can delete objects. It does not mean you can read objects or change the object ACLs. For this you need READ or FULL_CONTROL access on the object." <- this makes no sense. FULL_CONTROL does not mean you can read or change objects, to read or change an object you need FULL_CONTROL. Wat.

Comment: Read carefully:  FULL_CONTROL access to a _bucket_ ... does not mean you can read objects. (...)  For this you need READ or FULL_CONTROL access on the _object_. (My italics)